# drawRect: Not called for an NSView with a CAMetalLayer

Tags: macos, calayer, nsview, metal

I have a *layer-backed* (**not** *layer-hosted*) subclass of **NSView** called **MetalView**:

```
import Cocoa
import Metal

class MetalView: NSView {

    // MARK: Properties

    var metalLayer: CAMetalLayer {
        return layer as! CAMetalLayer
    }

    // MARK: - Overrides

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        initialize()
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        render()
    }

    override func drawLayer(layer: CALayer, inContext ctx: CGContext) {
        super.drawLayer(layer, inContext: ctx)
        render()
    }

    override func displayLayer(layer: CALayer) {
        super.displayLayer(layer)
        render()
    }

    override func makeBackingLayer() -> CALayer {
        return CAMetalLayer()
    }

    override var wantsUpdateLayer: Bool {
        return false
    }

    // MARK: - Initialization

    func initialize() {
        // Layer
        wantsLayer = true
        metalLayer.delegate = self
        metalLayer.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        metalLayer.pixelFormat = .BGRA8Unorm
        metalLayer.framebufferOnly = true
    }

    // MARK: - Rendering

    func render() {
        // Rendering
        metalLayer.frame = frame
        NSLog("rendering")
    }

}
```

The **render** method is not getting called. I tried setting **wantsUpdateLayer** to **true**. The **render** method gets called with I remove this part:

```
wantsLayer = true
metalLayer.delegate = self
metalLayer.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
metalLayer.pixelFormat = .BGRA8Unorm
metalLayer.framebufferOnly = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `wantsLayer` docs:

> If the wantsUpdateLayer method returns NO, you should not interact with the underlying layer object directly.

Setting values on `metalLayer` and modifying its frame count as "interact[ing] with the underlying layer object directly." You're not allowed to do that in this configuration. The layer doesn't belong to you. It belongs to the system. The system is free to create these caching layers any time it wants. It doesn't have to use it and there doesn't have to be just one. (Core Animation often creates extra layers; that's completely normal.)

If you want to interact with the layer directly, you should set `wantsUpdateLayer` to be `true` and then implement your drawing code in `updateLayer`. You shouldn't try to mix `drawRect:` with a layer you mess with directly.

For another version of this problem, see [Why is an empty drawRect interfering with a simple animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038951/why-is-an-empty-drawrect-interfering-with-a-simple-animation/35039660#35039660)

Comment: I tried setting `wantsUpdateLayer` to `true` and overriding `updateLayer`, but it doesn't work either. I also tried moving the code that sets up the layer into `makeBackingLayer`.

Comment: @GorGyolchanyan after setting wantsUpdateLayer, updateLayer doesn't get called when you call setNeedsDisplay?

Comment: I've called `metalLayer.setNeedsDisplay()` manually and it only causes the method `displayLayer(layer: CALayer)` to be called regardless of `wantsUpdateLayer`. The problem is that it doesn't get called upon resizing the view.

Comment: That's the default. Have you set the layerContentsRedrawPolicy? Layers typically avoid redrawing themselves unless you explicitly ask for it. Definitely not in a bounds change by default (they just scale or translate unless you ask for a full redraw).

Comment: Yes, it did work, thank you very much. Another problem remains, though: The view flickers and glitches out wildly when I update the view.

Comment: The most likely causes of that are either trying involve AppKit on threads other than the main thread, or not properly managing your pipelines in Metal. (Or trying to drive the draw loop with a timer or something like that.) Did you start with the Metal Programming Guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html and the sample projects and follow recommended usage? This setup doesn't feel much like Metal. Normally with Metal you're going to bypass as much of AppKit as you can.

Comment: I'm not using any more threads and I'm not using timers. I did start with the programming guide. Anyway, this is a bit off-topic. I'll do my research on this and make another question (possibly with a ready answer) regarding this.

Comment: @Hogdotmac yes, you are supposed to override it, not set it. If you see the original code, the OP was aware of that and it did not seem necessary to reiterate the fact.